# Highlight buttons one at a time

Tags: android

I am making an Android game modeled after the old Simon game. It is a little different in the layout as it is using a 3x3 layout of buttons. I am trying to get the buttons to light up one at a time inside the loop that randomly selects a button. The trouble I have is that all of the buttons light up at once and only the last (or first, not sure) changes back to the original color. I have tried very thoroughly to find an appropriate answer to my situation but have had no luck here or elsewhere. The button id(s) are in the butts[]. butts[0] is button 1, butts[2] ... Below is my attempt.

```
public void play()
{
  for(int x = 0; x <= numButtons; ++x)
  {
      spot = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
      playMe[x] = spot;
      //butts[spot].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#540115"));
      handler.postDelayed(new Runna(spot), (x+1)*1000); 
  }
}
class Runna implements Runnable 
{ 
  public Runna(int j2) 
  {
      butts[j2].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#540115"));
  }
  public void run() 
  {  
    butts[spot].setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the value of spot. It is global to the functions and you change it every time. It runs, but at the end there is still only one spot and EVERY runnable is trying to change that same spot.

Perhaps save spot in your runnable?

```
class Runna implements Runnable 
{ 
   int s;

   public Runna(int j2) 
   {
      s = j2;
      butts[s].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#540115"));
   }

   public void run() 
   {  
      butts[s].setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
   }
```

}

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I set one up another Runnable for setting the color and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to invalidate the button each time?

```
  public Runna(int j2) 
  {
      butts[j2].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#540115"));
      butts[j2].invalidate();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it has the same results.

Comment: Ok maybe you can rearrange the code where you post from the end of runnable telling it the next button to change.